# How do I get a fixed scrolling div to scroll with the rest of the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pq5ckkcg/4/. I basically need the whole window and div to scroll together no matter where the mouse is. How would I accomplish this?

```
<div id="bottomwrap">
<div id="element"></div>
<div id="element"></div>
<div id="element"></div>
</div>

#bottomwrap {
position:fixed;
top:45px;
right:0;
width:80%;
overflow-y:scroll;
bottom:0;
background-color:#666;
}
#element {
float:left;
width:200px;
height:300px;
background-color:#000;
margin:20px;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get what is needed, do you want the whole grey container to scroll?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/qndjW/6/)

Comment: I updated the jfiddle but I need both the div and rest of the window to scroll together so the div doesn't scroll over the white area above it.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent div needs to be relative positioned:

```
#bottomwrap {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:45px;
    float: right;
    width:80%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#666;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pq5ckkcg/3/

Comment: I need the white area above the #bottomwrap div to stay where it is and the whole window has a background image so I can't place a div over top.